# aligning all knitr tables in R markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have an rmarkdown document with several tables which are currently being printed with `kable(tbl, align = 'c')`, but I am wondering if it is possible to set an option to default print all of the tables in the document with center alignment.

Something like

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align = 'center')
```

except for centering table output rather than figure alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `knitr` options such as `fig.align` control how the figure is displayed with respect to the document.  A similar option for tables would control if the whole table was centered in the document or not.

To control the alignment of the contents within a table should be granular.  You could make a wrapper function for `kable` that would provide the default options you want.

```
my_kable <- function(x, align = "c", ...) {
  knitr::kable(x, align = align, ...)
}
```

The `my_kable` function will use the the wanted `align = 'c'` as default and the use of the `...` will let you pass any additional arguments needed for a specific table from `my_kable` to `kntir::kable`.